# compare time in bash script with ± x min

Tags: linux, bash, time, compare

I'm newbie in bash and need some advice.

I have a .txt file with a time stamp inside that is reloaded every x time, and each time stamps the current date and time.

```
"20221218-0841"
```

Now i have build a bash script to check the content and give me an answer if it is the same.

```
#!/bin/bash
time_status=`cat /root/test.txt | tail -c 14 | cut -d')' -f1`

date_now=`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M`

if [ "$date_now" == "$time_status" ]
then
    echo "OK - $time_status "
    date +%Y%m%d-%H%M
    exit 0
fi

if [ "$date_now" != "$time_status" ]
then
    echo "WARNING - $time_status "
    date +%Y%m%d-%H%M
    exit 1
fi
```

Everything is ok since now, the script does what it have to do, but i need to get ok for answer and exit with 0 when the time is ± 3 min not exactly the same.

Can someone provide some leads into this?

Comment: Can you output `date --version`? Do you have the `FreeBSD` date or `GNU` date/

Comment: date (GNU coreutils) 8.4

Comment: sorry if i wrote it wrong but totally new in here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the date, this way,

```
# Reading only the '%H%M' part from two variables using read and spitting
# with '-' de-limiter

IFS='-' read _ hourMinuteFromFile <<<"$time_status"
IFS='-' read _ currentHourMinute <<<"$date_now"

# Getting the diff only for the minutes field which form the last two
# parts of the variable above  

dateDiff=$(( ${hourMinuteFromFile: -2} - ${currentHourMinute: -2} ))

# Having the condition now for the difference from -3 to 3 as below,

if (( -3 <= ${dateDiff} <=3 )); then
    echo "OK - $time_status "
fi
```

Dry run,

```
time_status="20170318-1438"
date_now="20170318-1436"
dateDiff=$(( ${hourMinuteFromFile: -2} - ${currentHourMinute: -2} ))

echo "$dateDiff"
2
```

---

Another good coding practice is to avoid using ``, back-ticks for command-substitution and use `${..}` syntax and also do-away with a the useless use of `cat`,

```
time_status=$(tail -c 14 file | cut -d')' -f1)
date_now=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M)
```

Comment: Thanks @Inian you make my day :)

Comment: @IllyrianB: Happy to be of help. You could also upvote the answer by clicking on the small `^`, near the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the dates into seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC with `date +%s` and then perform the usual integer arithmetic on the result.

```
d1='2017-03-18 10:39:34'
d2='2017-03-18 10:42:25'

s1=$(date +%s -d "$d1")
s2=$(date +%s -d "$d2")
ds=$((s1 - s2))

if [ "$ds" -ge -180 -a "$ds" -le 180 ]
then
  echo same
else
  echo different
fi
```